# (Laravel) Undefined variable $name

Tags: laravel

I was making a CRUD user operation for admin dashboard, for the code, I copied my previous "view" that worked, and after I copied and changed some variables, the system detect that I haven't defined the variable `$name`.

**Here is the code that does not work**

```
<section class="content">
    
        <!-- Default box -->
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header">
         <h3 class="card-title">User</h3>
         <div class="card-tools">
           <div  class="box">
             <!-- Button trigger modal -->
             <a href=""> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="insertdatapegawai"> 
              + Add Data
             </button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="card-body" id="divtabel">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered projects">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th style="width: 1%" class="text-center">
                      No
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">
                      Username
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">
                      Email
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">
                      Role
                  </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          
          <tbody>
            @php
              $nomor = 1;
            @endphp
            @foreach ($data as $row)
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center"> {{ $nomor }} </th>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $row->$name }}  </td>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $row->$email}}  </td>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $role }} </td>
              <td>
                    <a href="tambahpegawai/{{ $row->id }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnedit" >Edit</button></a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btndelete" dataid="{{ $row->id }}">Delete </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @php $nomor++; @endphp
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

**Here is the Code that works:**

```
<section class="content">
    
        <!-- Default box -->
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header">
         <h3 class="card-title">Daftar Kegiatan</h3>
         <div class="card-tools">
           <div  class="box">
             <!-- Button trigger modal -->
             <a href="/tambahkegiatan/new"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="insertdatakegiatan"> 
              + Add Data
             </button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="card-body" id="divtabel">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered projects">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th style="width: 1%" class="text-center">
                      ID
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">
                      Nama
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">
                      NIM
                  </th> 
                  <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">
                      Kegiatan
                 </th>
                  <th style="width: 20%" class="text-center">
                      Jabatan
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 10%" class="text-center">
                      Jenis Kelamin
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 40%" class="text-center">
                      Foto
                  </th>
                  <th style="width: 30%" class="text-center">
                      Update
                  </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          
          <tbody>
            @php
              $nomor = 1;
            @endphp
            @foreach ($data as $row)
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center" scope="row">{{ $nomor }}</th>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $row->nama }}</td>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $row->nim }}</td>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $row->kegiatan }}</td>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $row->jabatan }}</td>
              <td class="text-center"> {{ $row->jenis_kelamin }}</td>
              <td class="text-center"> 
                @if ($row->foto !==null )
                  @if ($row->foto=='')
                  Tidak Ada Foto
                  @else 
                  <img src="{{ $row->foto }}" width="60%"> 
                  @endif
                @else 
              Tidak Ada Foto 
              @endif
              </td>
              <td>
                    <a href="tambahkegiatan/{{ $row->id }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnedit" >Edit</button></a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btndelete" dataid="{{ $row->id }}">Delete </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @php $nomor++; @endphp
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

**My Controller for the 1st code**

```
 public function users(Request $request)
    {
        $data = users::all();
        return view('users', compact('data'));
    }
```

**My Controller for the 2nd Code**

```
 public function daftarkegiatan (Request $request) {

        $data = daftar_kegiatan::all(); 
     
        return view ('daftarkegiatan',compact('data'));
    }
```

Comment: because you're trying ``$row->$name`` instead of ``$row->name``, ``$row->email`` and so on.

Comment: fyi, `<button>` inside `<a>` is invalid. Use CSS to style your `<a>` to look like a button

Comment: fyi, the `width` attribute in `<img>` must be an integer without a unit. Use CSS instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should write `{{ $row->name }}` instead of `{{ $row->$name }}`.

Also, instead of declaring unnecessary variables inside your blade, [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable) is already offering a solution for looping variable, you simply use
`{{$loop->iteration}}` instead of your `$nomor` variable.

Comment: kindly avoid adding answers which is likely caused by typos. :)